# Price conversion

Tags: wordpress, calculator

I need some help.
On a Wordpress real estate website, I would like to display the price in XPF next to the price in €.

The price function is:

```
    public static function format_price($price,$html = true){
        $return          = '';
        $currency_code   = self::get_general_option('currency');
        $currency_symbol = self::get_currency_symbol($currency_code);
        $currency_position = self::get_general_option('currency_position');
        switch ( $currency_position ) {
            case 'left' :
                $format = '%1$s%2$s';
                break;
            case 'right' :
                $format = '%2$s%1$s';
                break;
            case 'left_space' :
                $format = '%1$s&nbsp;%2$s';
                break;
            case 'right_space' :
                $format = '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s';
                break;
            default:
                $format = '%1$s%2$s';
        }

        $thousands_sep = wp_specialchars_decode( stripslashes(self::get_general_option('price_thousand_sep')),ENT_QUOTES);
        $decimal_sep = wp_specialchars_decode( stripslashes(self::get_general_option('price_decimal_sep')),ENT_QUOTES);
        $num_decimals = self::get_general_option('price_num_decimals');

        $price  = floatval( $price );

        if(!$html) {
            return self::number_format( $price, $num_decimals, '.', '', $currency_code );
        }

        $price  = self::number_format( $price, $num_decimals, $decimal_sep, $thousands_sep, $currency_code );
        if('text' === $html) {
            return sprintf( $format, $currency_symbol, $price );
        }

        //$price = preg_replace( '/' . preg_quote( self::get_general_option('price_decimal_sep'), '/' ) . '0++$/', '', $price );
        $return = '<span class="amount">' . sprintf( $format, $currency_symbol, $price ) . '</span>';

        return $return;
    }
```

The conversion rate is : 1€ = 119.33XPF

How can I edit the code to display the price like this for instance :
11933000XPF (100000€)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the floatval of the price in euros. If your conversion rate is a fixed value just convert like this:

```
$price_xpf = $price * 119.33;
```

The formatting of the price is working in exact analogy as the formatting for the price in euros.

Just for display do the following:

```
$return = '<span class="amount">'. sprintf( $format,"XPF",$price_xpf ) ."(". sprintf( $format, $currency_symbol, $price ) . ')</span>';
```

For any other adaption most basic programming skills will be helpful.